# SQL database not saving

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm relatively new to SQLite and I've been trying to modify a project made by people over at glitch. The app is supposed to save text to a database, and my project link is [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sql-?path=server.js%3A5%3A28). Although the logs don't show any errors. I can't get any data to save no matter what I do. (I changed the database file saving location from `.data/sqlite.db` to `/data.sqlite.db`). I assume this is some small issue I'm just new about, but I can't find anything about it on the internet.

```
app.use(express.static("public"));

// init sqlite db
const dbFile = "./data/sqlite.db";
const exists = fs.existsSync(dbFile);
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

// if ./.data/sqlite.db does not exist, create it, otherwise print records to console
db.serialize(() => {
  if (!exists) {
    db.run(
      "CREATE TABLE Dreams (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, dream TEXT)"
    );
    console.log("New table Dreams created!");

    // insert default dreams
    db.serialize(() => {
      db.run(
        'INSERT INTO Dreams (dream) VALUES ("test"), ("hi sam"), ("fortnite gaming chair 3d")'
      );
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Database "Dreams" ready to go!');
    db.each("SELECT * from Dreams", (err, row) => {
      if (row) {
        console.log(`record: ${row.dream}`);
      }
    });
  }
});

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/views/index.html`);
});

// endpoint to get all the dreams in the database
app.get("/getDreams", (request, response) => {
  db.all("SELECT * from Dreams", (err, rows) => {
    response.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
  });
});

// endpoint to add a dream to the database
app.post("/addDream", (request, response) => {
  console.log(`add to dreams ${request.body.dream}`);

  // DISALLOW_WRITE is an ENV variable that gets reset for new projects
  // so they can write to the database
  if (!process.env.DISALLOW_WRITE) {
    const cleansedDream = request.body.dream;
    db.run(`INSERT INTO Dreams (dream) VALUES (?)`, cleansedDream, error => {
      if (error) {
        response.send({ message: "error!" });
      } else {
        response.send({ message: cleansedDream+"success" });
      }
    });
  }
});

// endpoint to clear dreams from the database
app.get("/clearDreams", (request, response) => {
  // DISALLOW_WRITE is an ENV variable that gets reset for new projects so you can write to the database
  if (!process.env.DISALLOW_WRITE) {
    db.each(
      "SELECT * from Dreams",
      (err, row) => {
        console.log("row", row);
        db.run(`DELETE FROM Dreams WHERE ID=?`, row.id, error => {
          if (row) {
            console.log(`deleted row ${row.id}`);
          }
        });
      },
      err => {
        if (err) {
          response.send({ message: "error!" });
        } else {
          response.send({ message: "success" });
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

// listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? You need to post the code that's having a problem.

Comment: The code is in the link above! Thanks for the support! Ill try to edit my post so I include my code now too (its SQlite)

Comment: What are you doing to write data? Calling an endpoint? What excactly do the logs show? Do they show your code being executed?

Comment: BTW your glitch link is not accessible ("Well, you found a glitch.")

Comment: You're right! I fixed it, I'm very sorry, I'm trying to write data through SQlite by running commands, I'm still not 100% how it works exactly, but I believe it runs it with express. It shows the code being executed, and the logs say the record was saved successfully, but its not written in the actual file, and it doesn't show up ): Thank you so much for your time!